# Migration issues in python django?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have MySQL database in backed but when i change any model i does not reflect in backend

```
python manage.py makemigration app_name
python manage.py migrate
```

but it show no migrations applied

does mysql does nor support migrations

my model

```
class blog(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Comment: Django *does* support migrations for MySQL. You haven't shown enough information to tell why no migrations are applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try fake migration

```
python manage.py -fake app_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you already added `app_name` to `INSTALLED_APPS` list